# Why when i import an OBJ does it only appear as dots and not the actual solid?

Tags: modeling

I've been having an issue where when i import an OBJ file into blender it doesn't appear as the white "mesh" its just some kind of points. I was wondering how i could disable this, it used to be fine before but i think i must've accidently changed a setting. I will attach a screenshot below.

[image: The problem]

Comment: I must quickly add, this only happens with .OBJ files and not .FBX or anything else

Comment: Did you try to open the obj file with another software (meshlab for example)?
How does it look there?